# Linux, using mmzone.h to gather information on memory mangagement stats

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management, system-calls

I'm trying to create a system call that is able to report on memory management statistics. My goal is to be able to report on the following:

1. The Current number of free pages, over all memory zones.
2. The current number of pages used by slab allocator, over all memory
   zones.
3. The current number of pages in the active list, over all memory
   zones.
4. The current number of pages in the inactive list, over all memory
   zones.
5. The current number of pages in the active list whose reference bits
   are set, over all memory zones.
6. The current number of pages in the inactive list whose reference
   bits are set, over all memory zones.
7. The cumulative number of pages moved from the active list to the
   inactive list since the last machine boot.
8. Same as number seven but vice versa.

I'm not entirely knowledgeable on how to access this information. I know that in `mmzone.h` there is an array I can use called `vm_stat` injunction with the `enum zone_stat_item` and `enum node_stat_item` that will allow me to gather information about 1, but does `mmzone.h` contain information about 2 through 8. For example, would I use `vm_stat[NR_SLAB_RECLAIMABLE]` and `vm_stat[NR_SLAB_UNRECLAIMABLE]` to calculate 2? If not, where would I be able to access information that would satisfy 2 through 8? I'm confused because the variable names alone I find to be not very descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about 2,5,6,7, or 8. However, for 3 and 4 you can iterate through all the zones(using the `for_each_zone` macro that is also definedin `mmzone.h`), and use the enum zone_stat_item:

```
    enum zone_stat_item {
    /* First 128 byte cacheline (assuming 64 bit words) */
    NR_FREE_PAGES,
    NR_ZONE_LRU_BASE, /* Used only for compaction and reclaim retry */
    NR_ZONE_INACTIVE_ANON = NR_ZONE_LRU_BASE,
    NR_ZONE_ACTIVE_ANON,
    NR_ZONE_INACTIVE_FILE,
    NR_ZONE_ACTIVE_FILE,
    NR_ZONE_UNEVICTABLE,
    NR_ZONE_WRITE_PENDING,  /* Count of dirty, writeback and unstable pages */
    NR_MLOCK,       /* mlock()ed pages found and moved off LRU */
    NR_PAGETABLE,       /* used for pagetables */
    NR_KERNEL_STACK_KB, /* measured in KiB */
    /* Second 128 byte cacheline */
    NR_BOUNCE,
#if IS_ENABLED(CONFIG_ZSMALLOC)
    NR_ZSPAGES,     /* allocated in zsmalloc */
#endif
    NR_FREE_CMA_PAGES,
    NR_VM_ZONE_STAT_ITEMS };
```

If you take a look at `vmstat.h` you will find this useful function:

```
static inline unsigned long zone_page_state(struct zone *zone,
                enum zone_stat_item item){
long x = atomic_long_read(&zone->vm_stat[item]);
#ifdef CONFIG_SMP
if (x < 0)
    x = 0;
#endif
return x;
```

}

Which you can use to get the values for each of those elements in that enum. To get answer 3 you add the `NR_ACTIVE_ANON` with the `NR_ACTIVE_FILE` for each zone. For 4, you get the sum of `NR_INACTIVE_ANON` and `NR_INACTIVE_FILE` for each zone.

Let me know how you are able to get the remaining items if you end up figuring it out.

Comment: Well this might not be the answer, but at least it is a part of it, so thanks.

Comment: @MPK No problem. I have been trying to do something similar with a similar kernel. I found that the zone struct has a pglist_data *zone_pglist_dat, which has lruvec as a member. Supposedly this hold all the LRU lists for that zone, but I don't know how to traverse their pages.

So I'd check it out.